# Xampp fails to start on linux mint

Tags: debian, xampp

i had xampp working earlier on linux but i had phpmyadmin issues so i decided to reinstall everything i removed opt/lampp and Downloaded a newer version of xampp from their site now i try to start xampp

```
sudo /opt/lampp/lampp start
```

it gives errors

```
Starting XAMPP for Linux 5.6.14-3...
XAMPP: Starting Apache...already running.
XAMPP: Starting MySQL...ok.
XAMPP: Starting ProFTPD...fail.
XAMPP:  Another FTP daemon is already running.
```

i looked a little deep found

```
sudo lsof -i tcp:80
COMMAND    PID   USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
/opt/lamp 2055   root    4u  IPv6 121160      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
/opt/lamp 2243 daemon    4u  IPv6 121160      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
/opt/lamp 2244 daemon    4u  IPv6 121160      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
/opt/lamp 2245 daemon    4u  IPv6 121160      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
/opt/lamp 2246 daemon    4u  IPv6 121160      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
/opt/lamp 2313 daemon    4u  IPv6 121160      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
/opt/lamp 2316 daemon    4u  IPv6 121160      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
/opt/lamp 2317 daemon    4u  IPv6 121160      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
/opt/lamp 2319 daemon    4u  IPv6 121160      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
/opt/lamp 2320 daemon    4u  IPv6 121160      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
/opt/lamp 2321 daemon    4u  IPv6 121160      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
```

Any ideas what iam doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You installed the xampp stack while already having the native FTP installed and running in the system.

Also port 80 is not the port of the FTP service. Do

```
sudo lsof -i tcp:21
```

You have to kill this service and then do:

```
sudo /opt/lampp/lampp restart
```

Comment: You also have then to take out that ftp out of boot, or else it will go up again anytime you start the server, however someone is waiting for me.

Comment: Hey that worked perfectly `sooorajjj@Treako ~/Desktop/MerkMod $ sudo /opt/lampp/lampp restart
Restarting XAMPP for Linux 5.6.14-3...
XAMPP: Stopping Apache...not running.
XAMPP: Stopping MySQL...not running.
XAMPP: Stopping ProFTPD...ok.
XAMPP: Starting Apache...ok.
XAMPP: Starting MySQL...ok.
XAMPP: Starting ProFTPD...ok.`

Comment: but when i open https://localhost/phpmyadmin it says access denied  
ERROR:
MySQL said: Documentation
Cannot connect: invalid settings.

Comment: either phpadmin.conf is not properly configure or mysql is down. I do not know lampp that well, I normally used the default mysql, ftp, Apache and phpmyadmin that comes by default with linux.